# Why my ViewController releases after second call only, iOS ARC?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, release

ARC is used.
I have a simple two viewcontroollers one is starting viewcontroller second is custom UIImagepickerViewController (couple custom views on it)

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController { 
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) CameraController *cameraController;




@implementation ViewController
@synthesize cameraController;
-(void) showCame {
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{   
    self.cameraController = [[CameraController alloc] init];
    self.cameraController.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.cameraController animated:YES];
}   
}
```

But when i do  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; in camera controller it's not releasing a memory, only when i call it second time it calls dealloc of first instance and create second one.

Don't forget i use ARC

EDIT:
I just create blank project with two controllers, run it with instruments (Allocations) and i had 568Kb after app totally loading, then i click to show modal controller and dismiss it, and i got 642Kb(in second view controller i put 10 objects from IB)
The question is WHY ? why this data not destroyed totally, maybe caching or some ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are still retaining a strong pointer to it even though you are calling `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`. You have to set your pointer `self.cameraController = nil;` to tell ARC that you no longer want a pointer to it.

Comment: Thanks, now it calls dealloc proper, but not releasing memory

Comment: The memory will be released as and when ARC decides to do it. It doesn't necessarily happen straight away. As long as you aren't retaining any other pointers to it, then it will go away. If you have another pointer somewhere else to it, then you may still be leaking memory.

Comment: I thought ARC release this source right after it no longer needed, i have no pointers in other code.

Comment: @user735924: If the memory is not being released then you must have a strong pointer to it somewhere or you have a retain cycle.  For instance, a retain cycle could occur if the delegate property in CameraController is not declared as weak.

Comment: Cameracontroller is a UIImagePickerView, i don't know it's weak or not.

Comment: You've declared it as strong in your property!

Comment: Ok, how i should declare it ? retain and unsafe_unretained(this actually released the object right after init)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with declaring it strong. But you have to remember that it doesn't clear the memory straight away. You should spend some time reading the memory management docs that apple have written.